# Should the compiler give a warning if enum labels don't match type?

Tags: c++

I'd like the compiler to give a warning like:

"Banana is not a Color."

I understand that in the context of a switch statement the labels are promoted to int an the compiler is happy with 0 and doesn't care if it is "Green" or "Banana".

I was hoping -Wconversion for GCC would do the trick.

```
enum Color
  {
    Green = 0
  };

enum Fruit
  {
    Banana = 0
  };

int main()
{
  Color c = Green;
  switch (c)
    {
    case Banana:
      std::cerr << "Banana" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no required diagnostic for it in 6.4.2 of C++11, if that's what you mean by "should the compiler give a warning?". So the answer to the question you asked is "no", but maybe the question you want to ask is "are there any compilers in which I can enable such a warning, and if so how?" ;-)

Comment: Oh, and "the labels are promoted to int" -- it's not quite that simple. The labels are converted to the promoted type of `c`, which is at least `int`, and `int` is sufficient for the enum you defined, but it could be some other type, like `unsigned int` or `long long`.

Comment: Completely agree with Steve, that is a quality of implementation thing: a compiler can decide to warn about this if the implementor considers that it will help users in writing safe correct code, but the compiler is not required to do so.

Comment: Would it make sense for a C++03 compiler to decide to warn about this?

Comment: @Vote closers - I don't get these votes, it seems quite reasonable to me. The question is "how do I make my enums type safe?", with a sensible example problem. It's not a dupe that I can see and it's well scoped and answerable. It's a significant enough question in C++03 and C++98 that an international standards organisation went so far as to define a new solution to the problem.

Comment: @EddyPronk - I don't think it would make much sense to do that, it's perfectly legal as it stands and so much template meta programming depends upon being able to do such things it would be quite meaningless.

Comment: @awoodland Can you add a reference to a template meta program depending on this?

Comment: @EddyPronk - I've elaborated on that issue quite a lot. Basically I think it would chuck out hundreds of warnings for every boost header.

Comment: @woodland In cases where you depend on it you could write `switch(int(c))`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Strongly typed enums:

C++11 introduces strongly typed `enum`s, using `enum class`:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class Color
  {
    Green = 0
  };

enum class Fruit
  {
    Banana = 0
  };


int main() {
  Color c = Color::Green;
  switch (c)
    {
    case Fruit::Banana:
      std::cerr << "Banana" << std::endl;
      break;
    }
  return 0;

}
```

This code will fail exactly as you hoped:

> test.cc:18:17: error: could not convert '(Fruit)0' from 'Fruit' to
>   'Color'

Note: `enum class` doesn't cause `Green` and `Banana` to be in the enclosing namespace anymore, so you have to explicitly write `Color::` and `Fruit::` now, but you do *also* get the typesafety.

---

## The problems of warning in C++03

I don't think warning on this in C++03 would make much sense, it would basically just become noise.

People use `enum`s as compile-time constants quite often, even for things like bit-fields. For the warning to be meaningful you'd have to catch things like `enum { foo=0xf }; int c = foo;` and many codebases are scattered with `int`/`enum` conversions. (Allowing this would defeat the point of any stronger type checking).

Worse still though would be `enum`s used in almost any kind of meta programming context, where anonymous `enum`s are not only used freely interchangeably with `int` types on a regular basis:

```
template <int I>
struct is_odd {
  enum { value = !(I % 2) };
};

template <int I>
struct foo {
  static void bar() { /* I is true */ }
};

template <>
struct foo<0> {
  static void bar() { /* I is false */ }
};

int main() {
  foo<is_odd<201>::value>::bar();
  int i = is_odd<200>::value;
}
```

but they're also used recursively as local storage:

```
template <int N> 
struct factorial {
    enum {
        // This enum is *not* compatible with the one in N-1
        value = N * factorial<N - 1>::value
    };
};

template <> 
struct factorial<0> {
    enum { value = 1 };
};
```

Which is a part of the reason why `enum class` was required in order to introduce a non-breaking way of adding type-safety over the current state of `enum`s in C++. There would be so many warnings from existing code that a warning would be next to useless because of things like this.

Even in the fairly simple switch statement example you showed, something like this is legal:

```
#include <iostream>
enum Color { Green = 0x1, Red = 0x2 };
enum Fruit { Banana = 0x3 };

int main() {
  int v = Green|Red;
  Color c = Color(v);
  switch (c) {
  case Banana:
    std::cerr << "Banana" << std::endl;
    break;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Although this is legal here it's not hugely meaningful, but things like that are used fairly regularly and meaningfully in "bit-twiddling" C code still. The point of this example is that by allowing one `int`<->`enum` conversion *anywhere* it effectively means that being strict about the type of the `enum` later on is rendered meaningless. In the general case you can't detect if this kind of conversion has happened (it might have been in a different translation unit).

`enum class` is by far the nicest way of introducing such strictness cleanly without adverse effects on existing code.

Comment: I think you added some valid points here, however I don't see why a warning in the context of a switch statement would not be useful.

Comment: @EddyPronk - I've made another edit, which I hope shows why just allowing int->enum conversions makes warnings like that unhelpful.

Comment: I like `enum class` but it will take years before I can use C++11 features in real life. You added more about conversions, which is related, but not about the specific case I'm asking about. Again, in the specific context of a switch statement would it make sense to warn about the fact that we switch on type Color and have a case label of type Fruit. There should be enough context to warn about something fishy here.

Comment: @EddyPronk - the only reason a compiler can see that a warning might be helpful there is because it's such a trivial example that it can all be statically resolved at compile time. In the general case though that won't happen very often I suspect. Example: you have a function `void f(Color c) { switch (c) { ... } }` there's no way to be sure that the caller (which might not even be known at link time) hasn't done something like I showed to generate the value.

Comment: @EddyPronk - If you want to chat more I'm in http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec

Answer (score 6):

In C++11 (the new C++ standard) you can use `enum class` to create a strongly typed enum. See the [Wikipedia article on C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Strongly_typed_enumerations).

Example:

```
enum class Color { Green };
enum class Fruit { Banana };

// Put your main here - it would now fail
```

Comment: No, never mind, "enumeration type" is explicitly allowed as a conversion target. :)